# C++ - Parse like C++?

Tags: c++, windows, console, codeblocks

I'm creating a CLI and am having trouble parsing code like this:

```
io.print("Hello World!");
```

How would I go about parsing something like this without abusively using if statements to parse through the code char by char?

I want the console to print this on the window:

```
Hello World!
```

Comment: Traditionally, you'd start by writing a tokenizer (or finding a suitable one), and a grammar that combines the tokens into an AST or otherwise "understands" the syntax, and then evaluate that syntax.

Comment: I've written my tokenizer using a string vector & stringstreams. So all I can do is use IF statements?

Comment: No, a grammar isn't just `if` statements. You could use something like ANTLR directly, or search for something like 'C++ grammar parser'.

Comment: First of all, you don't want to write a C++ compiler. Either design a simpler language, or embed/spawn an existing C++ compiler. For typical scripting tasks, the former is almost infinitely preferable.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Agreed, although for typical scripting tasks, using an existing language is almost infinitely preferable!

Comment: @JBentley: Quite true -- I meant to mention that, but slipped up.

Comment: This question is asking a question similar to "how do I write Quake? I drew a pixel on the screen." -- the scope of answering "how do I write a complete compiler for a language like C++" is rather large.

Comment: I'm not making a C++ compiler, I'm making sort of a toy language. Just something to play around with.

Answer (score 2):

Technically this solves your problem as described:

```
std::map< std::string, std::function<void()> > program_map;

void define_programs() {
  program_map[ "io.print("Hello World!");\n" ] = []{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
  };
  program_map[ "io.print("Goodbye World!");\n" ] = []{
    std::cout << "Goodbye World!\n";
  };
};

int main() {
  // load parser:
  define_programs();
  // read program from user:
  std::string s;
  std::cin >> s;
  // compile and execute:
  if (program_map.find( s ) != program_map.end()) {
    (*program_map.find( s ))();
  } else {
    std::cout << "ERROR: unknown program.\n";
  }
}
```

but it probably doesn't solve the problem you want solved.

In general, parsing a C or C++-like language is a lot of work.  You can make your job easier by making an easier to parse language (LISP-like syntax is pretty darn easy to parse).

If you do want to parse a C/C++ like language, I'd advise you learn about grammars and lexers.  There are entire undergrad courses that end with writing a compiler for a language simpler than C/C++ -- C++ in particular is a really hard to parse language, and generally you'd want to not follow its conventions exactly.

Designing your grammar and writing a lexer (or teaching a pre-written lexer) for your grammar should go hand in hand.

When I design toy languages, I generally make them LISP like, because LISP like languages are really easy to work with.  So you have a command initializer `(`, a command, a list of arguments (which could be futher `(`'d), and the command executes when you reach the matching `)`.

So the equivalent of your code would be:

```
(io print "Hello World")
```

and now I have the `io` command (and object instances would be kinds of "commands") with a method print (which it reads from slot 2), and arguments to said method "Hello World".  The result of that, if I was feeling functional, would be a program that printed `Hello World` -- if not, it would do that as a side effect and return either an error code or nothing.

I'd then write an environment around this that defines some commands (including "make object"), probably some kind of quoting syntax (so I could define lambdas), etc.  I'd end up with a language that is a poorly designed, sub-optimal, restricted implementation of a small part of common lisp, which is traditional.

Only after I could do something like the above would I consider writing a parser for a harder to parse language like C/C++. And even then, I'd first rewrite the above toy language into some lexing/parsing framework, then write my C/C++ like language in the same framework.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would write HelloWorld in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

The string will be parsed at compile time, so there is no need to worry that it's printed inefficiently.

If I misunderstood your question (I only know CLI to stand for Command Line Interface), and you really want to parse C++ source code. I suggest you read a tutorial about a tool like yacc, and start with an open source C grammar.

This is a good yacc tutorial:
http://www.ds9a.nl/lex-yacc/cvs/lex-yacc-howto.html

This is a good starting point for a grammar:
http://www.computing.surrey.ac.uk/research/dsrg/fog/CxxGrammar.y

Comment: I think he's trying to write a C++ program that parses and executes code in another (likely ad-hoc) language.